# Application of the change of variable Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $B(0,1)$ be the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\|\cdot\|$ be the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$. To prove that $\int_{B(0,1)}\frac{1}{\|x\|^{\alpha}}dx$ is finite iff $\alpha<n$, I used the following change of variable:

$$\phi:  S^{n-1}\times ]0,1] \to B(0,1)\setminus \left\{0\right\}, (w,r)\mapsto wr$$

$$\phi^{-1}: B(0,1)\setminus \left\{0\right\}\to S^{n-1}\times ]0,1], x\mapsto (\frac{x}{\|x\|},\|x\|)$$

Applying the change of variable theorem, I need to calculate the determinant of the Jacobien matrix of $\phi$ which is not of dimenssion $n\times n$ according to what I wrote. Where is the problem here?